# Routing in MethodDecorator

Tags: angular

I have a method decorator on api calls that determines if a user has permissions to execute the api calls

```
@AuthDecorator([Constants.perm_read_document_type_indexid])
getDocumentTypes(Id: number): Observable<DocumentType[]> {
  return this.http.get<DocumentType[]>(`${environment.apiUrl}/documenttypes? 
Id=${indexId}`);
}
```

The Decorator takes in a permission type and checks local storage to see if the user has that permission.

```
export function AuthDecorator(permissions: string[]): MethodDecorator  {
 return function auth(target: Function, key: string, descriptor: any) {    
     const originalMethod = descriptor.value; 
     descriptor.value =  function (...args: any[]) {

        var scopes = new 
 localStorage.getItem(localstorage_permissions)).scope.split(" ");

        if(permissions.every(v => scopes.includes(v)))
        {
            return originalMethod.apply(this, args);
        }
        else{

            // redirect to unauth route
        }
    }
    return descriptor;      
   }
  }
```

I would like to redirect to an error page if the user does not have the appropriate permissions

I can do this via setting window.location.href but i would like to use angulars in built router. Is it possible to pass the router into the MethodDecorater? If not what would be the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Why don't you use an interceptor instead ?

Comment: And to answer you, no, you can't use the router into your decorator.